# whoosh exact match for a phrase

Tags: python, whoosh

I want to find a phrase in a document, I've used the codes in the quick start.

```
>>> from whoosh.index import create_in
>>> from whoosh.fields import *
>>> schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)
>>> ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
>>> writer = ix.writer()
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a", content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
>>> writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",  content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
>>> writer.commit()
>>> from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
>>> with ix.searcher() as searcher:
        query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse("first")
        results = searcher.search(query)
        results[0]

    result: {"title": u"First document", "path": u"/a"}
```

But then I find they will split the keywords into several single word and then search the document.
If I want to search a phrase like "the first guy here in the document", what should I do.

On the document ,it said, use

> "it is a phrase"

if I want to search for:

> it is a phrase.

That confuses me.

Besides, here is a class ,which seems can help me , but I don't know how to use it.

```
class whoosh.query.Phrase(fieldname, words, slop=1, boost=1.0, char_ranges=None)
 Matches documents containing a given phrase.
```

Update:
I use it in this way, but there is no matches.

```
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True),   content=TEXT)
ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a",
                 content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",
               content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
writer.commit()
from whoosh.query import Phrase

a = Phrase("content", u"the first")

results = ix.searcher().search(a)
print results
```

result:

> Top 0 Results for Phrase('content', u'the first', slop=1,
>   boost=1.000000) runtime=0.0>

Update according to theOther

```
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse(**'"first x document"'**)
results = searcher.search(query)
print results[0]
```

> result : Hit {'content': u"This is the first document we've added!",
>   'path': u'/a', 'title': u'First document'}>

I think there should be no matched result ,as there is no "first x document" in the document. Otherwise, it is not an exact match.

Comment: did you get the exact matching works?

Comment: All answers provided here are wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give `Phrase`  a `list` of words not a string as second argument, and also eliminate **the**  because it is a stop word:

```
a = Phrase("content", [u"first",u"document"])
```

instead of

```
a = Phrase("content", u"the first")
```

Read in documentation:

> ```
> class whoosh.query.Phrase(fieldname, words, slop=1, boost=1.0, char_ranges=None)
> Matches documents containing a given phrase.
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> fieldname – the field to search.
>
> ***words – a list of words (unicode strings) in the phrase.***

The natural use of phrase search in whoosh is by using **Quotes** `" "` in `QueryParser`:

```
>>> with ix.searcher() as searcher:
        query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse('"first document"')
        results = searcher.search(query)
        results[0]
```

**Update**: for `"first x document"` what it matches, it is because `x` and all one-character words are stop-words and are filtered.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your response firtslty.
But there are still some issues.
1. for the list , how can whoosh know the exact phrase combined by the words in the list. Are they combined one by one in sequence? Because I change the document content to "This is the first x document we've added!", and the phrase is Phrase("content", [u"first", u"document"]), but there is still a match.I want an exact match with the phrase.

Comment: 2. then I try the second way, document content is still "This is the first document we've added!", and the query is     query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse('"first x document"'), there is also a matched result. That seems to be not eaxt match with the query.

Comment: It matches because `x` is a stop-word and all one-character words. "first x document" after filtering the stopwords would be "first document".

Comment: @Assem this is not correct. see a MWE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688735/whoosh-phrase-search-return-empty-result-with-upper-case-character

Comment: @LearnToGrow may be its different in the newer versions

Answer (score 1):

To find a phrase in a content, use `phrase=True` when defining Schema as follows

```
schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), content=TEXT(phrase=True))
```

Then simply use double quotes within single ones as follows

```
query = QueryParser("content", schema=ix.schema).parse('"exact phrase"')
```

Comment: phrase=True is the default value for TEXT